clang-cl code coverage only one level deep
I am trying to generate code coverage for a big C++ project using LLVM tools on windows, but all I can manage to get is one-level deep coverage, is that normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?
Here's the setup:
I have two classes:
class A
{
  public:
    bool foo() {return true;}
};

class B
{
  private:
    A kung;

  public:
    bool bar(){return kung.foo();}
};

And I use Google Test for unit testing everything:
TEST(Suite, Name)
{
  B ba;
  EXPECT_TRUE(ba.bar());
}

The project is configured and generated with CMake/Ninja and compiled with clang-cl with the following flags: -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping. Compilation is done in release, with all optimisations off (-Xclang -O0).
Running the test creates the expected profraw file which I then feed into grcov to generate html and markdown reports.
grcov ./bin --llvm --branch --llvm-path <MS_LLMV_PATH> -b ./bin -s ./Sources -t html,markdown --ignore-not-existing -o .

The generated report shows only 50% coverage, and shows that B::bar() is called, but that A::foo() is not.
Is this behavior correct and expected? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a bug in the tools I am using?
PS: I also tried the --coverage compiler option, which generates .gcno files, then .gcda files after running the tests. But I get even weirder results in the report, with a lot of blank lines in the code browser (so neither covered nor uncovered!).

Optimization might make inlined code viewed as not covered.

In the actual codebase, the code is not inlined.

I'm not familiar with grcov.  Have you tried to use llvm-profdata merge.. followed by llvm-cov?  Did that work any differently?  Another possibility is to transfer the profraw files to a linux box and see if that gets a different result.

I'm getting even less code coverage with llvm-* tools... Maybe I'm using all this wrong? It's my first time foraying in this minefield :)
I'm going to try to build in Debug and test what happens (I've been trying to avoi this because our tests suite takes 4 hours in release...)

I am getting the same result in debug... I guess I must be doing something wrong somewhere, but seeing how complex the project is I'm not able to reproduce it exactly here

Turns out I am an idiot :)
I am generating both a static and a dynamic version for all my libraries, and I was only generation CC information for the dynamic libraries (and most of the Unit Tests are currently using the static libraries).
All is well now.
